# Galera + systemd: wsrep_notify_cmd fails with sudo (unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted)

Tags: sudo, systemd

We have a Galera cluster operational on CentOS 7 with sysv, and are looking into migrating to systemd. We are invoking a `wsrep_notify_cmd` to notify our application of changes in the node states, and we need to combine this with `sudo` because our application is in a directory with another user/group which `mysql` does not have access to.

With sysv init this is working fine as the command/script is initiated as root. With systemd, the command/script is initiated under the `mysql` user - so we need to configure sudoers in order to make it work. Or so we thought.

After switching to systemd, I kept seeing `sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted` in our logs, so I did some testing/debugging with the idea to first start a script which `mysql` DOES have rights to, and that script will in turn pass on the `wsrep_notify_cmd` arguments to another script (`/data/app/notify.sh`) using `sudo`.

**Note:** SELinux is disabled.

#### MySQL server config

MySQL server (test) configuration: `wsrep_notify_cmd='/mysql/notify.sh'`

#### Sudoers config

`/etc/sudoers.d/mysql` is configured as follows:

```
Defaults:mysql !requiretty
Defaults:mysql umask=0007

Cmnd_Alias NOTIFY = /bin/bash /data/app/notify.sh*
mysql ALL=(app_user) NOPASSWD: NOTIFY
```

#### Manual test

Now, `sudo su - mysql` and then manually running `/mysql/notify.sh` works fine:

```
[mysql@testhost /mysql]$ /bin/sudo -u app_user /bin/bash /data/app/notify.sh --status Synced
[mysql@testhost /mysql]$
```

The `/data/app/notify.sh` script, being ran as `app_user` writes all passed on parameters to a file - and successfully does when running the above command manually:

```
[root@testhost /data/app]# cat output.log 
--status Synced
```

#### Same thing, but from within systemd mysql service init

However, when doing `service mysql start`, the `/mysql/notify.sh` script will not do its job as it should and instead will deny access to *any* `sudo` command: `sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted`.

I am running this script using `#!/bin/bash -xv` and redirecting stderr to a log file:

```
[mysql@testhost /mysql]$ cat debug.log 

file=/mysql/args.log
+ file=/mysql/args.log

echo $USER
+ echo mysql

ARGS="$@"
+ ARGS='--status Synced'

/bin/sudo -K
+ /bin/sudo -K
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
/bin/sudo -u app_user /bin/bash /data/app/notify.sh $ARGS
+ /bin/sudo -u app_user /bin/bash /data/app/notify.sh --status Synced
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
```

As you can see, the same command which I was able to run manually from the `mysql` user shell is **NOT** working when being invoked from the same script when being ran as part of systemd `service mysql start`.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to defeat systemd security here, you can modify the Unit's capabilities, eg:

`# systemctl show mysql | grep Cap`

`-- CapabilityBoundingSet=16384`

`# vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`

`-- CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_SETGID CAP_NET_RAW CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_ADMIN`

`systemctl daemon-reload`

`systemctl restart mysqld`

`systemctl show mysql | grep Cap`

`-- CapabilityBoundingSet=2126016`

Note that fewer Capabilities may be required, this was just a quick test

Don't modify that actual file, use eg /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/MY_SPECIAL.conf

Comment: While setting additional capabilities is needed, it is not sufficient. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Setting capabilities as described in the other answer is needed, but not sufficient, at least if MariaDB is used instead of mySQL.
 In addition to adding capabilities, `NoNewPrivileges` must be false (or no). 
Because `NoNewPrivileges` is implied by `PrivateDevices` which is set in `mariadb.service`, we must override this to false.

I was successful in Ubuntu 18 LTS (where Galera doesn't work with the supplied mysql package) with these settings in `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/mariadb-sudo.conf` (there is no need to edit the original `mariadb.service`):
`[Service]
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETGID
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
PrivateDevices=false`

Because `mariadb.service` has `Alias=mysql.service`, it can be started with
`service mysql start` so this seems to match the original question.